# Верстка элементов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Народ, подскажите как правильнее сверстать этот блок? А именно серые палки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Серые палки.....

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что по запросу `верстка серых палок` ни кто искать не будет...

Answer (score 2):

```css
.lines {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

.lines::before,
.lines::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: lightgray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 10px;
  left: 50%;
}

.lines::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) translate(-50%, -20px) skew(25deg);
          transform: rotate(15deg) translate(-50%, -20px) skew(25deg);
}

.lines::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg) translate(-50%, -20px) skew(-25deg);
          transform: rotate(-15deg) translate(-50%, 20px) skew(-25deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="lines">
    <p>Народ, подскажите как правильнее сверстать этот блок? А именно серые палки. Народ, подскажите как правильнее сверстать этот блок? А именно серые палки. Народ, подскажите как правильнее сверстать этот блок? А именно серые палки.</p>
</div>
```